# ASP.NET Repeater Group by Data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using a FormView Repeater to display my data in a table. However, I want to group the same data together. I have total 4 categories. Ford, Nissan, Toyota, and Volvo. The data row for each brand of car is different. How to group it and make it show only once?

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='<%# Container.DataSource %>'>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Ford</td>
                <td align="left"><%# Eval("Carcode")%></td>
                <td align="left"><%# Eval("PlateNum")%></td>
                <td align="left"><%# Eval("StoreName")%></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

My results from the Data Table:

```
Car_Name   Car_Code Plate_Number Store_Name
  Ford       1234      abc123     storeA
  Ford       1121      abc111     storeB
  Ford       2311      aaa111     storeC
  .....................................
```

Expected Results:

```
Car_Name   Car_Code Plate_Number Store_Name
  Ford       1234      abc123     storeA
             1121      abc111     storeB
             2311      aaa111     storeC
  Nissan     1234      abc123     storeA
             1121      abc111     storeB
             2311      aaa111     storeC
```

Comment: Are you looking to handle the grouping on the UI or at the source? The latter may allow you to more easily build your UI. Please include the code where you retrieve the data.

Comment: Car_Name column's data is hard coded. Is there any way to group that?

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup around the company name like:

```
<td align="right">
  <asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>' /> 
</td>
```

Create a private variable

```
private _lastCompany As String = ""
```

In the event handler

```
Public Sub ItemDatabound(e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) ..
   Dim data As ClassType = CType(e.Item.DataItem, ClassType)
   If (data.CompanyName = _lastCompany) Then
      e.Item.FindControl("lblName").Visible = False
   End If

   _lastCompany = data.CompanyName
End Sub
```

You can use the ItemDataBound event to get the value of the row, and compare to a variable that has the previous item.  Hide the control anytime the previous row matches the current row.